# Saving detected facial landmarks into a file

Tags: c++, opencv, dlib

I'm trying to import facial landmark points from webcam or video

using dlib into a file . I can display all detected landmarks on the terminal

but  it is only saving the first and second landmark ponits (x,y) into the

output file , and not saving all the detected landmarks into

the output file

```
#include <dlib/opencv.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>
#include <dlib/image_processing/render_face_detections.h>
#include <dlib/image_processing.h>
#include <dlib/gui_widgets.h>

using namespace dlib;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
try
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    if (!cap.isOpened())
    {
        cerr << "Unable to connect to camera" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    image_window win;

    frontal_face_detector detector = get_frontal_face_detector();
    shape_predictor pose_model;
    deserialize("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat") >> pose_model;


    while(!win.is_closed())
    {
        // Grab a frame
        cv::Mat temp;
        cap >> temp;


        cv_image<bgr_pixel> cimg(temp);


        std::vector<rectangle> faces = detector(cimg);

        std::vector<full_object_detection> shapes;
        for (unsigned long i = 0; i < faces.size(); ++i)
      {  

               full_object_detection shape = pose_model(cimg, faces[i]);

        cout << "number of parts: "<< shape.num_parts() << endl;
            cout << "pixel position of first part:  " << shape.part(0) << endl;
   cout << "pixel position of second part: " << shape.part(1) << endl;
  shapes.push_back(pose_model(cimg, faces[i]));


   const full_object_detection& d = shapes[0];
           ofstream outputfile;
           outputfile.open("data1.txt");


                outputfile<< shape.part(0).x() << " " << shape.part(0).y() << endl;
                outputfile<< shape.part(1).x() << " " << shape.part(1).y() << endl;


              }

        win.clear_overlay();
        win.set_image(cimg);
        win.add_overlay(render_face_detections(shapes));
    }
}
catch(serialization_error& e)
{
    cout << "You need dlib's default face landmarking model file to run this example." << endl;
    cout << "You can get it from the following URL: " << endl;
    cout << "   http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2" << endl;
    cout << endl << e.what() << endl;
}
catch(exception& e)
{
    cout << e.what() << endl;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Am I wrong or you want to save all landmarks when you have only:
`ofstream outputfile;
outputfile.open("data1.txt");
outputfile<< shape.part(0).x() << " " << shape.part(0).y() << endl;
outputfile<< shape.part(1).x() << " " << shape.part(1).y() << endl;`
And even not closing the file correctly. Try with `for` statement.

Comment: I put  shape.part(0).x() and shape.part(0).y()   as an example ,              when I listed landmarks (e.g from 0 to 10 ) only the first and second detected landmarks are saved  .                                                            The   ofstream outputfile; is already inside for loop

Comment: Have you tried other types for output to file like `FILE`?

Comment: I have just tried .csv output but it is the same saving only the first two values